# Why did I see Spider-Man with Captain America's shield in his hand?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, trailers, spider-man-homecoming

In a movie trailer for the new ***Spider-Man*** movie coming out soon, they played certain key scenes and showed Spider-Man kicking butt, but the thing that got me is when he landed on a metal crossbeam outside on a construction site with one arm extended out - and with ***Captain America's*** shield in his hand.

***Tell me, why did I see this?***

Comment: Because your eyes were pointed at the screen.

Comment: i just watched all 6 trailers that I know of, and I don't see a scene like that. What you're describing sounds like it's from _Civil War_ -- there are fan-made "trailers" splicing together the Spidery Cam footage from the international trailers with the matching _Civil War_ scenes. Could that be what you saw?

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with that film, this is a new spider man coming out, because im from Australia, I watched it last night, no knowing what time it would be for you but I know I saw spider man holding captian america's shield. I never saw that trailer before and I believe it was the first time the trailer showed and it said in cinemas ..., so from that, I know it isn't already from a current and already out movie.

Comment: I think you're missing the point: the Spider-Man international trailers _include footage_ of the Civil War movie in them, because that's where Peter's story starts out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spider-Man: Homecoming is following the Captain America: Civil War.

I've seen the same trailer - and the clip with Spidey holding Cap's shield seems to be lifted straight from the CA:CW movie during the airport fight.

Later in the trailer (or in another trailer), Peter is boasting to his friend about meeting Iron Man and the Avengers, and how he stole Captain America's shield from him.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably describing [Captain America: Civil War](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/) scene.

Spider-Man was in the movie and fought (Kinda) Captain America.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Probably part of the scene was in one of the trailers (Official or fan made, I don't know)

Comment: As to the question of **why** this was shown in the trailer: To communicate to the viewer that the upcoming Spiderman movie is built on the Spiderman we saw in the Civil War movie.